# How can I remove Camera app on Cyanogenmod?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I am running Cyanogenmod on my SamSung phone.

Can you please tell me how can I remove the Camera app on the phone?

Comment: If Cyanogenmod works just like Android 4 (and I have no idea if it does, never having used it), then you can go to "Settings", choose "Apps", tap on the Camera app; tap "Uninstall Updates" if that button is visible; then tap "Disable".  The app's icon will disappear from the launcher, and (as far as I know) from everywhere else _except_ the Settings page, where you can, of course, re-enable it later if you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really just want to remove it (which, fair warning, may cause problems with the system; I have no idea) you can:

- Use `adb` to delete the .apk file: `adb shell rm /system/app/Camera.apk`. You may need to first elevate to root (`adb shell` and then `su` from the shell).
- Use [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup&hl=en) to uninstall it

A potentially safer route that people take is to use Titanium Backup Pro to "freeze" the app, causing it to essentially act as though it is uninstalled without actually removing it (so it can be "defrosted" later if needed). This does require the Pro version, though.

Comment: An app called NoBloat can freeze (disable) apps in the free version.

Answer (score 3):

The camera app will be usually named Camera.apk, located in **/system/app**. To delete this first clear the data stored by the app in **/data/data/com.sec.android.app.camera/** or something similar

- Using Root Explorer, find the file, click mount rw and delete it.
- Using terminal emulator,

  1. Acquire root privileges

     ```
     su
     ```
  2. Mount system in read write mode

     ```
     mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system
     ```
  3. Delete the file

     ```
     rm /system/app/Camera.apk
     ```
- Using adb

  1. Mount system in read write mode

     ```
     adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system
     ```
  2. Delete the file

     ```
     adb shell rm /system/app/Camera.apk
     ```
- Using titanium backup, select the app and click uninstall

Comment: When i use 'adb' method, I did 'adb shell mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system ', but it said 'mount: Operation not permitted'. Any idea?

Comment: is your phone rooted?

Comment: Yes. I am running cyanogenmod and I have  'Superuser' installed.

Comment: can you try: adb shell (enter) su (enter)mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock03 /system(enter)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to delete or replace system files ''at your own risk", first make sure you're rooted. Then install NQ mobile security. From the home screen of NQ, slide to the left to access ROM App Manager. Once you are there, MAKE SURE YOU BACK UP THE FILE BEFORE UNINSTALLING IT so you can restore it if anything goes south.
Good luck and just say thank you if i help!